# Create keys for dictionary based on length of list of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following list:

```
my_list = [[['pd', 1],
           ['pd_de', None],
           ['pd_amnt', '$10.00']],
           [['pd', 1],
           ['pd_de', '5/1/19 '],
           ['pd_amnt', '$100.00 '],
           ['pd', 2],
           ['pd_de', '5/1/20 '],
           ['pd_amnt', '$200.00 ']],
           [['pd', 1],
           ['pd_de', None],
           ['pd_amnt', None]],
           [['pd', 1],
           ['pd_de', '5/1/19 '],
           ['pd_amnt', '$300.00 '],
           ['pd', 2],
           ['pd_de', '5/1/20 '],
           ['pd_amnt', '$600.00 '],
           ['pd', 3],
           ['pd_de', '6/1/18'],
           ['pd_amnt', '$450.00']]]
```

Using this, I would like to create a list of dictionaries. I am dong the following to create a list of dictionaries,

```
list_dict = []

for i in my_list:
    temp_dict = {}
    for j in i:
        temp_dict[j[0]] = j[1]
    list_dict.append(temp_dict)
```

And I am getting an output like this, which I do not want,

```
[{'pd': 1, 'pd_de': None, 'pd_amnt': '$10.00'},
 {'pd': 2, 'pd_de': '5/1/20 ', 'pd_amnt': '$200.00 '},
 {'pd': 1, 'pd_de': None, 'pd_amnt': None},
 {'pd': 3, 'pd_de': '6/1/18', 'pd_amnt': '$450.00'}]
```

I need an output like this,

```
[{'pd_1': 1, 'pd_de_1': None, 'pd_amnt_1': '$10.00'},
 {'pd_1': 1, 'pd_de_1': '5/1/19', 'pd_amnt_1': '$100.00', 'pd_2': 2, 'pd_de_2': '5/1/20 ', 'pd_amnt_2': '$200.00 '},
 {'pd_1': 1, 'pd_de_1': None, 'pd_amnt_1': None},
 {'pd_1': 1, 'pd_de_1': '5/1/19', 'pd_amnt_1': '$300.00','pd_2': 2, 'pd_de_2': '5/1/20', 'pd_amnt': '$600.00','pd_3': 1, 'pd_de_3': '6/1/18', 'pd_amnt_3': '$450.00'}]
```

If you see above, they are okay when the list inside has a length of 3. If it is more than 3, then it does not give the correct result.

I am also not sure how to create `"_"` in keys (i.e. 'pd_1') when I create keys for dictionary.

How can I achieve my desired output?

(Note: Not sure how to name the title, I said length of list, I might be wrong there because I am not familiar with pythonic terms)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest it is edited now. Sorry!

Comment: Note that dict is unordered structure - keys may not be ordered by "groupes". We could have `'pd_1': 1,
  'pd_2': 2,
  'pd_3': 3,
  'pd_amnt_1': '$300.00 ', ...` - is that acceptable ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest My ultimate goal is to create a pandas dataframe after I have the list of dictionaries. I have to test it out. With all these answers I am trying to test each of them and some terms are new. Let me get back to you on that.

Comment: see my updated answer with pandas involved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I found a really cool way to do this.
- you can use `defaultdict` to increment key everytime you see it. And then add it your `result` dictionary.

```
list_dict = []

from collections import defaultdict

for i in my_list:
    temp_dict = {}
    incr = defaultdict(int)
    for j in i:
        incr[j[0]] += 1
        temp_dict[j[0] + '_' + str(incr[j[0]])] = j[1]
    list_dict.append(temp_dict)
```

Output:

```
[{'pd_1': 1, 'pd_de_1': None, 'pd_amnt_1': '$10.00'},
 {'pd_1': 1,
  'pd_de_1': '5/1/19 ',
  'pd_amnt_1': '$100.00 ',
  'pd_2': 2,
  'pd_de_2': '5/1/20 ',
  'pd_amnt_2': '$200.00 '},
 {'pd_1': 1, 'pd_de_1': None, 'pd_amnt_1': None},
 {'pd_1': 1,
  'pd_de_1': '5/1/19 ',
  'pd_amnt_1': '$300.00 ',
  'pd_2': 2,
  'pd_de_2': '5/1/20 ',
  'pd_amnt_2': '$600.00 ',
  'pd_3': 1,
  'pd_de_3': '6/1/18',
  'pd_amnt_3': '$450.00'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Retaining the order of items:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

# my_list = ...

res = []
for l1 in my_list:
    d = OrderedDict()
    for l2 in l1:
        if l2[0] == 'pd':
            sfx = l2[1]
        d[f'{l2[0]}_{sfx}'] = l2[1].strip() if isinstance(l2[1], str) else l2[1]
    res.append(d)

df = pd.DataFrame(res)
print(df)
```

The output:

```
   pd_1 pd_de_1 pd_amnt_1  pd_2 pd_de_2 pd_amnt_2  pd_3 pd_de_3 pd_amnt_3
0     1    None    $10.00   NaN     NaN       NaN   NaN     NaN       NaN
1     1  5/1/19   $100.00   2.0  5/1/20   $200.00   NaN     NaN       NaN
2     1    None      None   NaN     NaN       NaN   NaN     NaN       NaN
3     1  5/1/19   $300.00   2.0  5/1/20   $600.00   3.0  6/1/18   $450.00
```

Comment: this method is lightning fast! Sorry, I really have to give correct answer to @Poojan since I did not mention about data frame in the post. You solution is elegant to create a data frame. Honestly, don't know how to handle these situations in SO.

Answer (score 1):

You can use additional variable (`counter`) to find key "index" which doesn't exist in dictionary yet:

```
result = []
for sub_list in my_list:
    temp = {}
    for key, value in sub_list:
        counter = 1
        while f"{key}_{counter}" in temp:
            counter  += 1
        temp[f"{key}_{counter}"] = value
    result.append(temp)
```

A bit more efficient solution will be to store counters into dict and increment them once key used:

```
result = []
for sub_list in my_list:
    counters = {}
    temp = {}
    for key, value in sub_list:
        if key in counters:
            counters[key] += 1
        else:
            counters[key] = 1
        temp[f"{key}_{counters[key]}" ] = value
    result.append(temp)
```

Using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) you can write it a bit shorter:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = []
for sub_list in my_list:
    counters = defaultdict(int)
    temp = {}
    for key, value in sub_list:
        counters[key] += 1
        temp[f"{key}_{counters[key]}"] = value
    result.append(temp)
```

Comment: your first solution gives correct results, your second solution and third solutions are giving wrong results. It keeps incrementing "_<countervalue>". Not sure if I can upvote yet.

Comment: @user9431057, sorry, wrote it without IDE.. Solution is to put `counters` initialization incide loop, edited.

Answer (score -1):

The reason you are getting this is because when you set a key in a dictionary to something, it will override any previous data. For example, you have this dictionary `x = ["a":1, "b":2, "c":3]` if you do `x["d"] = 4` it will then be `["a":1, "b":2, "c":3, "d":4]` but if you then do `x["a"] = 3` it will be `["a":3, "b":2, "c":3, "d":4]`.

The solution for you is to add each item into the dictionary with a number after the tag to represent which tag it is.

```
list_dict = []

for i in my_list:
    temp_dict = {}
    for j in i:
        a = 1
        while j[0]+"_"+str(a) in temp_dict:
            a += 1
        temp_dict[j[0]+"_"+str(a)] = j[1]
    list_dict.append(temp_dict)
```

Comment: This one is so time consuming. :(